# php mysql result not displayed

Tags: php, mysql

so here is the code. it worked with xampp 1.7 which I used previously. am now using the latest version of xampp. could this be the problem? i can insert the data into the database. but couldn't display the links inside the table. it shows a blank column with no text. can someone please help me with this?

```
     <?php 
     $host="localhost"; // Host name 
     $username="root"; // Mysql username 
     $password=""; // Mysql password 
     $db_name="phoenix_db"; // Database name 
     $tbl_name="questions"; // Table name 
     // Connect to server and select database. 
     mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
     mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); 
     $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC"; // ORDER BY id DESC is order         
     $result=mysql_query($sql); 
     ?> 
     <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> 
     <tr> 
     <td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>#</strong></td> 
     <td width="53%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Title</strong></td>
     <td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Views</strong></td> 
     <td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Replies</strong></td> 
     <td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td> 
     </tr> 
     <?php 
     // Start looping table row 
     while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
     { 
     ?> 
     <tr> 
     <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
     <? 
     echo $rows['id']; 
     ?>
     </td> 
     <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="viewq.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
     <? echo $rows['title']; ?></a>
     <BR>
     </td> 
     <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['view']; ?></td> 
     <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['reply']; ?></td> 
     <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td> 
     </tr> 
     <?php 
     // Exit looping and close connection 
     } 
     mysql_close(); 
     ?>
```

Comment: Start by removing the quotes in `mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")` to read as `mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)` and `mysql_select_db("$db_name")` to `mysql_select_db($db_name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello can you please try this

I have just changed `<? to <?php`

and make sure the column names and data is present in the database.

```
<?php 
     $host="localhost"; // Host name 
     $username="root"; // Mysql username 
     $password=""; // Mysql password 
     $db_name="phoenix_db"; // Database name 
     $tbl_name="questions"; // Table name 
     // Connect to server and select database. 
     mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
     mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); 
     $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id DESC"; // ORDER BY id DESC is order         
     $result=mysql_query($sql); 
     ?> 
     <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> 
     <tr> 
     <td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>#</strong></td> 
     <td width="53%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Title</strong></td>
     <td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Views</strong></td> 
     <td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Replies</strong></td> 
     <td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td> 
     </tr> 
     <?php 
     // Start looping table row 
     while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
     { 
     ?> 
     <tr> 
     <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
     <?php 
     echo $rows['id']; 
     ?>
     </td> 
     <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="viewq.php?id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
     <?php echo $rows['title']; ?></a>
     <BR>
     </td> 
     <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['view']; ?></td> 
     <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['reply']; ?></td> 
     <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td> 
     </tr> 
     <?php 
     // Exit looping and close connection 
     } 
     mysql_close(); 
     ?>
```

Comment: and yeah the column names are exactly the same as in the database

Comment: <? was supported by old versions of php.. as you mentioned that you have upgraded new version of xampp. so new version of php uses ?php and not <?  and have you tried the above answer?

Comment: if it worked for you then please mark the answer as useful as it will be useful to others in future with same problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your code..

use this

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ 
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($rows);
echo "</pre>"; 
......
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change in
>
> & in

```
 mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");
```

> remove " "

```
<?php 
 $host="localhost"; // Host name 
 $username="root"; // Mysql username 
 $password=""; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="phoenix_db"; // Database name 
 $tbl_name="questions"; // Table name 
 // Connect to server and select database. 
 mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB"); 
 $sql="SELECT * FROM ".$tbl_name." ORDER BY id DESC"; // ORDER BY id DESC is order         
 $result=mysql_query($sql); 
 ?> 
 <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"> 
 <tr> 
 <td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>#</strong></td> 
 <td width="53%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Title</strong></td>
 <td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Views</strong></td> 
 <td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Replies</strong></td> 
 <td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td> 
 </tr> 
 <?php 
 // Start looping table row 
 while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
 { 
 ?> 
 <tr> 
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
 <?php 
 echo $rows['id']; 
 ?>
 </td> 
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="viewq.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>">
 <?php echo $rows['title']; ?></a>
 <br>
 </td> 
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['view']; ?></td> 
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['reply']; ?></td> 
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td> 
 </tr> 
 <?php 
 // Exit looping and close connection 
 } 
 mysql_close(); 
 ?>
```